# PHP returns loads of blank spaces

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

i have a login script that uses AJAX, but i have a problem with the code that i cannot work out.

Here is the code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loginForm").submit(function(){

            $("#report").removeClass().addClass('loader').html('Loading...').fadeIn(1000);

            $.post("check_login.php",{ username:$('#signin_username').val(),password:$('#signin_pwd').val()},function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data == "TRUE"){
                    document.write(data);
                    console.log("YEP");
                    $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){            
                        $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('log').fadeTo(900,1,function(){                 
                            document.location='members/index.php';
                        });           
                    });
                }
                else if(data == "FALSE"){
                    console.log("NOPE")
                    $("#report").fadeTo(200,1,function(){             
                        $(this).html('Username or password error.').addClass('error').fadeTo(900,1);
                    });     
                }
            });
            return false; 
        });

        $("#password").blur(function(){
            $("#login_form").trigger('submit');
        });
});
```

FORM:

```
<div id="login_form">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div id="signup_link">
                <a href="signup/">Signup Now</a>
            </div>
            <div id="report"></div>
            <form action="" method="post" id="loginForm">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="username">Email: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="signin_username" name="signin_username" required="required" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="pwd">Password: </label>
                        <input type="password" id ="signin_pwd" name="signin_pwd" required="required" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login"/>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="members/forgotPass.php" class="forgot_pass">Forgot Password</a></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and PHP file called by js:

```
require_once 'members/classes/Membership.php';

# Make instance of membership class
$membership = new Membership();

$true = "FALSE";
$false = "FALSE";

if(!empty($_POST))
{       
    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $pwd        = $_POST['password'];

    if($test = $membership->validate_user($username, $pwd))
        echo $true;
    else 
        echo $false;
}
else 
{
    echo "Details werent entered";  
}
```

Basically the method the php script is calling checks the database to see if the users details match and if they're allowed to login, if so returns true if not returns false (These are the only two values it will return.

So it works file until we get back into the js code, note the first "console.log" the output of this seems to have loads of white space before the word that im looking for something like this:

"

TRUE"

The space above the true is nothing so when i test `if(data == "TRUE")` it's never true.

Either something strange is happening or i'm missing something really silly. Can anyone see whats wrong?

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Btw, have you noticed you have both $true = "FALSE"; and $false = "FALSE"; in your PHP file?

Comment: Ahh thats an error i put in while trying to get it to work, just trying random things. Thanks for pointing it out @RolandoIsidoro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you haven't got any include files that are outputting whitespace. It's easy to make that mistake.

Comment: removing the `?>` tag from the end of your php files often helps eliminate this, however not everyone likes this approach.

Comment: Is there a reason that it would do this? @MrE

Comment: Like Frits said in his answer, whitespace at the beginning or end of your php files could indeed be the cause for this. Removing the `?>` at the end of your php files will help you eliminate this issue with whitespace at the end of your php files. However it is completely up to you, as I stated, it is not everyone who likes doing that.

Comment: It seems you guys were right, as a note i didn't remove the ?> tag but i found some whitespace before and after the ?> i removed this and it works a charm. Never would have thought of that, wouldn't even know how to research it to be honest so thanks a lot for you help.